# php get not get value after urlrewrite

Tags: php, url-rewriting, get

I want to url rewrite from `page.php?search=`*keywords*  to `page/`*keywords*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]    
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/?$ page.php?search=$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
```

Then type some url like: `localhost/page/hello`, I can not get `hello`

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];//search=
echo $_GET['search'];//empty
?>
```

Comment: Why aren't the RewriteConds before RewriteRules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "hello" part of the url should be $1, not $2 - you're only extracting one part of the url with that regex. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/?$ page.php?search=$1
```